# Unix time with NSDate reveals erroneous results

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, unix-timestamp

I live in Denmark (UTC + 1 ) and I am working with a webapi that sends my app a unix timestamp since 1970-1-1 00:00:00. The time is in the future (train depatures)
If I check the timestamp in Numbers or Excel it gives me the correct time

To calculate the number of minutes until the train departures I do like this:

```
let unixTimeTrainDeparture = 1419327780 //(or some time in the future)
let unixRightNow = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
let minutesToDeparture = (Int(unixTimeTrainDeparture) - Int(unixRightNow))/60
```

However this gives 60 minutes too much?

And If I do a

```
let dateTest = NSDate(string: "1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000")!
```

will give me 1 jan 1970 :01:00:00 +0000

This does not make sense to me. It is like the timeIntervalSince1970 gives me 3600 sec too less, as it starts from 1970-1-1 01:00 rather than 00:00? It this a bug or is it the way it should be?
I can correct the time by using the 
`let tz = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    let seconds = tz.secondsFromGMTForDate(NSDate())`

and then subtracting the seconds from my result. However, what happens when we move into summer time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timeIntervalSince1970` always gives the time in GMT. Your `unixTimeTrainDeparture` is probably the time in GMT+1, which explains the 60 minute difference (or 120 minutes in summer time). Same goes with the string conversion - you input a GMT time and it outputs the date in whatever timezone you have configured (I'm guessing your computer's setting is GMT+1 as well).

When working with timezones, always start with GMT/UTC and don't do any timezone conversions until displaying the date to the user.

Do you have any control over the web API? If so - configure it to send GMT instead. This should completely avoid time zone and daylight savings issues.

If you cannot do that you will have to implement some function to convert the timestamp yourself, accounting for the possibility that a future timestamp could be in a different timezone (eg daylight savings). `NSTimeZone` might be very useful for this!

Hope I have understood your problem correctly!

Edit, added example that should handle DST:

```
// Date far in the future in DST, replace this
let unixTimeTrainDeparture = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1436447418)
let now = NSDate()

// Assume unixTimeTrainDeparture is in the Copenhagen timezone
let tz = NSTimeZone(name: "Europe/Copenhagen")

// This is 3600 in non-DST, otherwise 7200
let offset = tz!.secondsFromGMTForDate(unixTimeTrainDeparture)

let realUnixTimeTrainDeparture = Int(unixTimeTrainDeparture.timeIntervalSince1970) - offset

let timeToDeparture = realUnixTimeTrainDeparture - Int(now.timeIntervalSince1970)
```

Comment: I have no control over the webapi. I also assumed that the API time had 3600 sec too much, but then why does that error not show up in my spreadsheet where I make a 1970-1-1 00:00:00 + ApiTimeStamp. This should in my opinion give me the same offset, but it does not.

Comment: I added some sample code, it assumes that the time you receive from the API is always in the Danish timezone.

Comment: Hi Thanks. Yes that works (se the first code I submitted), but my worry is what will happen when we change time to summertime. My assumption is, that the offset will grow to 7200. But thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I think I made a mistake, the updated example should handle the DST offset too! Try it with different dates and you'll see the offset change accordingly.

Comment: @user1700737 please mark my answer as correct if you feel that my solution is appropriate.

Comment: pls give my question a one up, if you feel it's a good question